# is the answer contained in the question when it is well formulated?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, political-philosophy, philosophy-of-mind, psychology

we expect others especially authorities to give us answers. can anyone have answers to our own questions except oureselves when letting the question being unconsciously processed and give space for insight to happen?

Comment: Is your question whether answers to a question are found virtually in the question?

Answer (score 2):

the teacher which explain everything to the student is not a good teacher. a good teacher give some clues but leave the student with the ability of discovering by himself. to explain everything in detail is good for making the student stupid, a mere parrot, an imitator repeating what others said without understanding what is saying. to explain in detail stops the capacity for true learning in the student.

Answer (score 1):

When the pursuit is that of knowledge then a well designed question certainly lends itself to its answering in an effective manner. Even if no answer is forthcoming a well formulated question should at least help serve to guide the self in seeking out directions of exploration to help come to such an answer.

A person who chooses to question also opens him or herself up to possible answers and those who seek are more inclined to find - even if such be through stumbling upon such answer through observation or happenstance.

When the pursuit is that of piquing the minds of others (or projecting a view in an indirect fashion) a well formulated question will better serve to impress the underlying views concerned.

I discount the generally interrogative "Is it not so that...?" since I feel that the standoffish/ pressuring nature of such questions may fall outside the scope of your intentions with this question.

Instead I speak more of the questions that gently draw the potential respondent to consider elements in the world around them that they generally would not. For instance - "Why do you suppose that we tend to seek out the answers or advice of authorities when we have questions?" (Not seeking an answer - its a simplistic example)

---

Addendum - It is also pertinent to add that a poorly formulated question, by contrast, will have a tendency of either confusing the respondent or lead their train of thoughts in different directions from that intended. While accidents can be positive in their results, they generally serve the purposes of neither the seeker of knowledge nor the subtle imparting of views.

Comment: intelligent people can read between the lines.